# Make case repeat if correct answer is not given

Tags: ruby, case

I have a `case`-construction that checks against standard user input. I would like to repeat (or do nothing) if the given answer is not given by the user. I have five options for `case` construction: `"s"`, `"t"`, `"c"`, `"a"`, and `"o"`. I want to repeat (or do nothing but repeat) if the user does not give on of those five answers.

```
choice = gets.chomp.downcase

case choice
when 's'
    @klass = "S Klass"
    @extra = "S Extra"              
    puts "S Story"
when 't'
    @klass = "T Klass"
    @extra = "T Extra"
    puts "T Story"
when 'c'
    @klass = "C Klass"
    @extra = "C Extra"
    puts "C Story"
when 'a'
    @klass = "A Klass"
    @extra = "A Extra"
    puts "A Story"
when 'o'
    @klass = "O Klass"
    @extra = "O Extra"
    puts "O Story"
end
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
loop do
  choice = gets.chomp.upcase
  case choice
  when "S", "T", "C", "A", "O"
    @klass = "#{choice} Klass"
    @extra = "#{choice} Extra"              
    puts "#{choice} Story"
    break
  end
end
```